# I am getting two errors in my CSS code, "Expected RBRACE", "Unexpected RBRACE", and "Expected LBRACE"

Tags: html, css, animation, text

I am new to CSS and HTML as I am learning it in my free time for my livestreaming.
I am attempting to create a custom text animation of the text being cut in half, with the left half floating up and the right half floating down (possibly in future changing to where they both just swing and fall downwards).

I'm not fully sure what to try at this point, I have added, removed, and messed with the code in every way I can think of. I have scoured the internet and this forum and found nothing to help me.

```
#keyframes slideup {
    0% {
        top: 50%
    }        
    30% {
        top: 50%;
    }        
    90% {
        top 40%;
    }
    100%: {
        top: 40%;
}
```

I expect the left half of the text to float upwards while the right side floats downwards, but that is not happening and I'm assuming its because of my code.

Comment: You're missing a `;` after the first `top: 50%`.

Comment: You are missing a closing `}` so I'd start there.

Answer (score 0):

```css
p{
position:absolute;
top:50%;
left:50%;
animation:slideup 1s infinite;
}
@keyframes slideup {
    0% {
        transform:translateY(0);
    }        
    100%{
      transform:translateY(-100px)
}
}
```

```html
<p>text<p>
```

this is how u create animation!

Comment: Thank you for the help!
But I am also trying to have the text cut in half. Basically what I've done is copied the text twice and they appear on top of each other, but I want the right half and the left to go in opposite directions (either up and down or left and right) away from each other.

Comment: hey look at this demo https://codepen.io/iziz96/pen/YbReGB?editors=1100